# Android Studio throws Exceptions after adding a new view, a new layout or a new drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, exception

I have been facing a weird problem with Android Studio.

Android Studio throws different nonsense exceptions if I do one of these;
-Add something new to my layout (TextView, ImageView, LinearLayout, etc.)
-Create a new layout
-Add a new drawable
-Change the name of a class/enum or move it to another directory.

When I face these exceptions I have to always Clean my project or even Invalidate Caches and Restart. It is getting frustrating. Yesterday, for the whole day I was trying to fix exceptions that did not exist and somehow suddenly everything start working perfectly!

Have you ever face something similar to this? If so how did you manage to fix it? How may I get rid of this problem?

Device: MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) - macOS 11.5.2

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Comment: did you updated all sdk tools?

Comment: @sasikumar yes everything is up to date. I even freshly installed Android Studio this morning and check all the updates one by one.

Comment: can you try with new simple project? . if its happens again uninstall everything and clear system caches and temp files. Then install from the begining